# Json object will not deserialize in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to access this api the documentation quite good but I am having trouble deserlizating the object.

You can you my test url here will change api key after.

https://services.marinetraffic.com/api/vesselmasterdata/v:3/APiKey/imo:9661792/protocol:jsono

This is the object class.

```
public partial class MaraineApiData {
    [JsonProperty("METADATA")]
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DATA")]
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
}

public partial class Datum {
    [JsonProperty("MMSI")]
    
    public long Mmsi { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IMO")]
            public long Imo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PLACE_OF_BUILD")]
    public string PlaceOfBuild { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("BUILD")]
    public long Build { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("BREADTH_EXTREME")]
    public long BreadthExtreme { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SUMMER_DWT")]
    public long SummerDwt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DISPLACEMENT_SUMMER")]
    public string DisplacementSummer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CALLSIGN")]
    public string Callsign { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FLAG")]
    public string Flag { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DRAUGHT")]
    public string Draught { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LENGTH_OVERALL")]
     public long LengthOverall { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FUEL_CONSUMPTION")]
    public string FuelConsumption { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SPEED_MAX")]
    public string SpeedMax { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SPEED_SERVICE")]
    public string SpeedService { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LIQUID_OIL")]
    public string LiquidOil { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OWNER")]
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MANAGER")]
    public string Manager { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MANAGER_OWNER")]
    public string ManagerOwner { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("VESSEL_TYPE")]
    public string VesselType { get; set; }
}

public partial class Metadata {
    [JsonProperty("TOTAL_RESULTS")]
    public long TotalResults { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TOTAL_PAGES")]
    public long TotalPages { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CURRENT_PAGE")]
    public long CurrentPage { get; set; }
}
```

But this is how I am using to get my data from the api.

```
public async Task<List<Metadata>> GetMarineApiData(string IMOCode) {
   string VechnicleDataURL = $"vesselmasterdata/v:3/{ApiKey}/imo:{IMOCode}/protocol:jsono";
   List<Metadata> _result = new List<Metadata>();
   var uri = new Uri(string.Format(APIUrl + VechnicleDataURL, string.Empty));
   var response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
     var byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
     var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
      _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Metadata>>(content);
   }
  return _result.ToList();
 }
```

Error

O> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})

> into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MISSystem.Dal.Metadata]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (

Comment: How is it of type string when i run it it shows fields in the debug 
{"METADATA":{"TOTAL_RESULTS":1,"TOTAL_PAGES":1,"CURRENT_PAGE":1},"DATA":[{"MMSI":"319094900","IMO":"9661792","NAME":"DILBAR","PLACE_OF_BUILD":"","BUILD":"2016","BREADTH_EXTREME":"24","SUMMER_DWT":"1230","DISPLACEMENT_SUMMER":"","CALLSIGN":"ZGFO","FLAG":"KY","DRAUGHT":"","LENGTH_OVERALL":"156","FUEL_CONSUMPTION":"","SPEED_MAX":"","SPEED_SERVICE":"","LIQUID_OIL":"","OWNER":"","MANAGER":"","MANAGER_OWNER":"BURGESS YACHTS","VESSEL_TYPE":"YACHT"}]}

Comment: My bad your url didn't work out of the box so had to copy paste a bit and somehow ended up with another result, so deleted my comment. That said that's still not a `List<Metadata>` but a `MarineApiData`

Comment: @Knoop I tired that as well still didnt work

Comment: And once again the advise to remove the call with your api-key from your post and just add that call result (that's all we're interested in anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The api string you have provided returns not an array but an object:

```
{
 "METADATA": { ...},
 "DATA": [{...}]
}
```

Try to replace

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Metadata>>(content);
```

with

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MaraineApiData >(content);
```

and it should be fine.